# PostgreSQL pg_dump creates sql script, but it is not a sql script: is there a way to get pg_dump to create a standard sql script?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm running pg_dump to create a script to automate the creation of a system like this:

```
pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:ohdsi@127.0.0.1:5432/OHDSI -t webapi.* > webapi.sql
```

This creates a sql script, but it is not really a sql script as it has code in it like what is shown below.

When this script is run as a sql script, it fails giving the error shown below.

Is there a way to get pg_dump to create a sql script that is standard sql and can be executed as a sql script?

**Code sample from sql generated by pg_dump:**

```
COPY webapi.cohort_version (asset_id, comment, description, version, asset_json, archived, created_by_id, created_date) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: concept_of_interest; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: webapi; Owner: ohdsi_admin_user
--

COPY webapi.concept_of_interest (id, concept_id, concept_of_interest_id) FROM stdin;
1   4329847 4185932
2   4329847 77670
3   192671  4247120
4   192671  201340
```

**Error seen when running the script generated by pg_dump:**

```
--
-- Name: penelope_laertes_uni_pivot id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: webapi; Owner: ohdsi_admin_user
--
ALTER TABLE ONLY webapi.penelope_laertes_uni_pivot ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('webapi.penelope_laertes_uni_pivot_id_seq'::regclass)

--
-- Data for Name: achilles_cache; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: webapi; Owner: ohdsi_admin_user
--
COPY webapi.achilles_cache (id, source_id, cache_name, cache) FROM stdin

Error executing: COPY webapi.achilles_cache (id, source_id, cache_name, cache) FROM stdin
.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: COPY commands are only supported using the CopyManager API.
  Where: COPY achilles_cache, line 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.RuntimeSqlException: Error executing: COPY webapi.achilles_cache (id, source_id, cache_name, cache) FROM stdin
.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: COPY commands are only supported using the CopyManager API.
  Where: COPY achilles_cache, line 1
    at org.yaorma.database.Database.executeSqlScript(Database.java:344)
    at org.yaorma.database.Database.executeSqlScript(Database.java:332)
    at org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.tools.build.postgres.build.A04_CreateAtlasWebApiTables.exec(A04_CreateAtlasWebApiTables.java:29)
    at org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.tools.build.postgres.build.A04_CreateAtlasWebApiTables.main(A04_CreateAtlasWebApiTables.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.RuntimeSqlException: Error executing: COPY webapi.achilles_cache (id, source_id, cache_name, cache) FROM stdin
.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: COPY commands are only supported using the CopyManager API.
  Where: COPY achilles_cache, line 1
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeLineByLine(ScriptRunner.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:71)
    at org.yaorma.database.Database.executeSqlScript(Database.java:342)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: COPY commands are only supported using the CopyManager API.
  Where: COPY achilles_cache, line 1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeStatement(ScriptRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.handleLine(ScriptRunner.java:165)
    at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeLineByLine(ScriptRunner.java:102)
    ... 5 more
```

**--- EDIT ------------------------------------**

The --inserts method in the accepted answer gave me exactly what I needed.

I ended up doing this:

pg_dump --inserts --dbname=postgresql://postgres:ohdsi@127.0.0.1:5432/OHDSI -t webapi.* > webapi.sql

Comment: What do you mean by "standard SQL"? I cannot see any "code" in the snippet you posted, it's regular SQL.

Comment: how exactly are you trying to run the dump file? it is supposed to work perfectly with psql command and a bash terminal. can you provide more information?

Comment: How are you trying to run that script? The `pg_dump` output is meant to be run using the `psql` command.

Comment: It would be convenient if the output from pg_dump was standard sql.  If it was I could just run the script as a sql script to automate the creation of the database.  But because it is something that can only be read by psql I need to figure out a way to call psql  from my Java application that is trying to automate the creation of this database rather than just executing a sql script of standard sql.

Comment: I’m not even sure if there is any database at all that supports the entire SQL Standard and only the SQL standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client tool you are using to restore the dump cannot deal with the data from the (nonstandard) `COPY` command being mixed into the script. You need `psql` to restore such a dump.

You can use the `--inserts` option of `pg_dump` to create a dump that contains `INSERT` statements rather than `COPY`. That will be slower to restore, but will work with more client tools.

However, your wish to get a standard SQL script is hopeless. PostgreSQL extends the standard in many ways, so a database cannot be dumped with a standard SQL script. Note, for example, that indexes are not defined by the SQL standard. If you are looking to transfer a PostgreSQL dump to a different RDBMS, you will be disappointed. That is more difficult.